# Using Xpath to parse a specific part from XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I am wondering how to use the "if" conditionals when I want to parse a particular section from XML file. This is the XML section I want to parse:

```
   <match date="13.06.2014" id="3551904" status="16:00" time="16:00">
    <home name="Mexico"/>
    <away name="Cameroon"/>
    <odds>
     <type id="768" name="Over/Under">...</type>
     <type id="769" name="Handicap">
     <bookmaker id="769" name="Betwin">
     <bookmaker id="779" name="10Bet">
      <handicap name="-0.75">
        <odd name="1" value="2.43"/>
      </handicap>
      <handicap name="+0.75">
        <odd name="2" value="1.53"/>
      </handicap>
      <handicap name="-0.5">
        <odd name="1" value="2.09"/>
      </handicap>
      <handicap name="+0.5">
        <odd name="2" value="1.78"/>
      </handicap>
```

Controller:

```
        def new
        f = File.open("odds_sample.xml")
        doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
      @test = doc.xpath("/odds/league/matches/match[./odds/type/bookmaker]")
```

View:

```
       <tbody>
        <% @test.each do |w| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= w.at_xpath("./home")['name'] %></td>
    <td>VS</td>
             <td><%= w.at_xpath("./away")['name'] %></td>
             <td><%= w.at("bookmaker").children.attr("value") %></td>
             <td><%= w.at("bookmaker").children[1].attr("value") %>             </td>
             <td><%= w.at("bookmaker").children[2].attr("value") %></td>

  </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
```

Assuming I always want to get the "odd value" nearest to 2 for "odd name = 1", How am I going to parse this with ruby? Thanks.

Comment: Use `nokogiri`.. Awesome gem for this tasks.

Comment: Are you asking about "if" conditionals in XPath? in Ruby? If in XPath, what version of XPath do you have access to?

Comment: @LarsH I was using nokogiri, so I guess that is version 1.0? I will update my code in controller and view. Thanks.

Comment: `nokogiri -v` at the command line will tell you about Nokogiri's environment.